# Powell vs Levmar

Tags: numerical-optimization

I'm learning about the application of numerical optimization, and noticed that in one of the programs that I'm using it uses [Powell's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powell%27s_method) to get parameters of a piece-wise function, and [Levmar](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/) if the function can be expressed as a simple formula (such as $x^a + b$). I think non-linear least squares (Levmar) could have been used for both.

I wanted to understand when to use Powell's method and when to use Levmar?

A specific question I have is given reasonable initial starting points to both, will both of them  converge to the same minimum?